# Why simulator triggers an event when I didn't change its value?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I tried to use a simple example to describe my question; please refer to the following code:

```
wire test_wire;
logic test_logic;
 
initial begin
   fork 
       begin 
           $display($time, "wire before!");
           @(test_wire);
           $display($time, "wire after!");
       end
 
       begin
           $display($time, "logic before!");
           @(test_logic)
           $display($time, "logic after!");
       end
    join_none
end
```

I think by default, `wire` was assigned as high-z, `logic` was assigned as x, and I intentionally didn't do any assignment for this `wire` and `logic` since I would like to understand the difference.

But, I found the simulation will print as follows:

```
0 wire before!
0 logic before!
0 wire after!
```

I would like to ask why the simulator triggers `@(test_wire)` at zero time only? There is no other code changing its value, so I am getting confused.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in the simulator you are using.  I ran the code on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/VwBa), and 4 simulators did not display `0 wire after!`.  Only the Cadence simulator displays it.

Answer (score -1):

This is simulator specific I guess. I tried it with different simulators.
You can check **dave_59**'s answer on this site - [default values of wire and reg](https://www.edaboard.com/threads/default-values-of-wire-and-reg.328687/)

Also, you can execute the code you have given with different simulators here - [Run Code](https://edaplayground.com/x/uvDW)

The outputs For different Simulators:

1. Cadence Xcelium

   [image]
2. Aldec Riviera Pro

   [image]
3. Mentor Questa

   [image]
4. Synopsys VCS

   [image]